# How to exclude a only substring(not their characters) from the string using java regex?

Tags: java, regex

When I use `[^abc]` it excludes `a`,`b`,`c` but I want to exclude only `abc` not `a`,`b`,`c`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is required but perhaps this example may help: https://regex101.com/r/dDjGT6/1

Answer (score 2):

Just in principle? There are several ways to do it, depending on your context. You could use a negative lookahead, for example, which will assert what the following string must not look like.

Example text:

```
aba abc abx
```

Expression:

```
\b(?!abc)\w{3}\b
```

Matches:

```
aba, abx
```

You should update your question with context if you want specific help.